# Java application installer as a windows service or startup

Tags: java

I am using netbeans to create a project, and the final result needs to be an installer, that when you install the app, it would automatically turn itself on after every computer reset.
I was looking (still am) for any software that would help me, but cant find anything.. I found a simple install creator and it makes an installer but it doesnt automatically puts the app as a windows service (i could use the CMD to make it as a service after the installation, but i want it to be automatic).

Another alternative is that the installer would put the application exe in the users startup group, but again, i want it to do so automatically.

Can someone recommend me some simple software for this.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to launch the application on startup?

Comment: For what OSs do you want installers? Does it have to be Open Source or can you use also commercial software?

Comment: I want that the application would launch everytime on startup, i am using windows os, basically i want an installer that would put this app into startup folder, or make it run as windows service

Answer (score 0):

Try [Install4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html). Although it is not free.

> install4j offers full support for generating and installing services (daemons). For services, install4j generates service executables on Windows, startup items on Mac OS X and start/stop scripts on Unix/Linux platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a right SO question.

Any how, have a Look at [WhatInStartup](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/what_run_in_startup.html) 
(it's free)

Create a exe Jar file of your program, add just add to it.

To do it in a easy way,Look at [Jar2Exe](http://download.cnet.com/Jar2Exe/3000-2213_4-10521671.html)

Answer (score 0):

We have used [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) at my job, and it has worked fine for years. It is not free though.